# Incorrect annotation for property "message" in class "Error"

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

After update typo3 from v 7.x to 8.x I have error

There is no @var annotation for property "message" in class "Error".

More detail you can find here : https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great that you found the issue, and great that you submitted a bugreport! You seem to know the issue and have found a fix aswell so you can easily submit it as a contribution to the core

TYPO3 has a contribution guide that helps you get it all setup

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ContributionWorkflowGuide/